# Duvida com números vizinhos em Python

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar nesse código com o objetivo de calcular números vizinhos(números em comum) em duas Arrays, mas não retorna output.

```
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
input1 = input()
input2 = input()
input1.split(", ")
input2.split(", ")
while i < len(input1):
    while j < len(input2):
        if input1[i] == input2[j]:
            result = input1[i]
            print(result)
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: O que seriam "números vizinhos"? E quais serão as entradas do programa? Qual deverá ser a saída?

Comment: Só lembra que quando for trabalhar com números que vieram de um input, você deve converte-los para float ou int, por exemplo, float(input1), pois você está recebendo uma string, checa também aquele if

Comment: Carlos, os números em comum de duas arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é bem simples, basta utilizar o `raw_input()` ao envés do `input()`.
Basicamente o `input()` ele vai receber e interpretar como uma lista de inteiros, e quando você tentar usar o `input1.split(", ")` ele não vai reconhecer o comando, mas quando você utilizar o `raw_input()` você cria uma lista de string, e nessa lista você utilizar o `input1.split(", ")` além de poder transformar novamente para `int` se necessário.

Comment: Mas o erro no era no split, pois eu testei a array. E estou programando em Python 3. Mas obrigado pela resposta.